# MYSQL select DISTINCT values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table:

```
$taxonomy_table (
                `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                `media_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `playlist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                INDEX `media_id` (`media_id`),
                CONSTRAINT `mqap_taxonomy_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`) REFERENCES {$media_table} (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
            )";


media_id     type      title
------------------------------
23           tag       fashion
23           tag       beauty
23           category  foo
24           tag       fashion
24           category  foo
```

I want to select item with ALL these tags="fashion, beauty" and category="foo", so only media_id=23.

The query is:

```
$query = "SELECT media_id
                FROM {$taxonomy_table}
                WHERE type='tag' AND title IN ($arg) 
                AND type='category' AND title IN ($arg2)
                AND playlist_id=%d
                GROUP BY media_id
                HAVING count(DISTINCT title) = $total";
```

$arg = "fashion, beauty", $arg2="foo"

```
"SELECT media_id 
 FROM wp_mvp_taxonomy 
 WHERE type='tag' 
   AND title IN (%s,%s) 
   AND type='category' 
   AND title IN (%s) 
 GROUP BY media_id 
 HAVING count(DISTINCT title) = 3"
```

But this its not returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `OR`, also add parenthesis because `AND` has precendence.

```
$query = "SELECT media_id
          FROM {$taxonomy_table}
          WHERE playlist_id=%d 
            AND (   ( type='tag' AND title IN ($arg) )
                 OR ( type='category' AND title IN ($arg2) )
                )
          GROUP BY media_id
          HAVING count(DISTINCT title) = $total";
```

Comment: I want to fetch rows with ALL tags and category not ANY.

Comment: Yes, this do that. because found 3 distinct titles. But a `type` **cant** be 'tag' **AND** 'category' at the same time. So you need `OR`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `OR`:

```
"SELECT media_id 
 FROM wp_mvp_taxonomy 
 WHERE (type='tag' AND title IN (%s,%s))
   OR  (type='category'  AND title IN (%s))  -- here
 GROUP BY media_id 
 HAVING count(DISTINCT title) = 3"
```

Original:

```
WHERE type = 'tag' ... AND type ='category' => always false
```